# Unexpected Behaviour of UIViewController autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, cordova, ios7

I have an iOS app built using PhoneGap/Cordova  (3.0), and I'm trying to get it updated to work correctly with iOS 7 and Xcode 5, particularly the new-style status bar.

I don't have a lot of experience with native iOS programming or Objective-C, so I'm pretty much just figuring things out as I go along, and this is also my first post on StackOverflow, so please forgive me if I get anything wrong.

The issue I've run into is this:

PhoneGap includes the InAppBrowser plugin, which is a separate WebView displayed on top of the app (which my app uses mainly for Twitter login, if there are no native Twitter accounts set up). This doesn't seem to have been updated at all yet for iOS 7, so the status bar appears on top of whatever web page is loaded in the plugin. I've been trying to deal with this by resizing the WebView itself so that it's height is 20px lower, leaving a gap for the status bar.

This is the main code that I've been modifying to try to achieve the desired result:

```
- (void)createViews {

CGRect webViewBounds = self.view.frame;

webViewBounds.origin.y += 20; //added by me
webViewBounds.size.height -= 20; //added by me
[self.view setFrame: webViewBounds]; //added by me

webViewBounds.size.height -= FOOTER_HEIGHT;

self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webViewBounds];
self.webView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.webView];
```

(The WebView is also resized elsewhere in the plugin, based on self.view.frame and subtracting a bit from the height to allow for the InAppBrowser toolbar buttons at the bottom of the screen)

So this sizes and positions self.view.frame to fit underneath the status bar, and then all further WebView sizing/resizing is based on that size and position. This almost works perfectly, except that the height of the WebView itself always ends up being too big (the bottom of the webpage ends up underneath the toolbar). It made absolutely no difference how much I subtracted from self.view.frame.size.height. The only thing which made it work as expected was commenting out the autoresizingMask on the WebView (but of course that caused other issues)

After a lot of experimentation (and pulling a large quantity of my hair out), I've finally narrowed it down. It seems that when the WebView is auto-resized, it's being treated as if its frame.origin.y is set to 0 (it gets resized to fit correctly from there), even though it's actually 20. When set to 0, it resizes correctly, but when set to any other value it ends up being too high by that amount, even though the value of its height has already taken that into account.

So, I can deal with this by modifying every WebView height change to subtract its origin.y value (20px), and this appears to work correctly, but surely (and looking at the actual numbers seems to confirm) this is subtracting the extra height twice. Does this make any sense? Am I missing something here?